# How to handle $ctrl. in AngularJS?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components, cumulocity

I have a Methode from an API. It returns a promise which resolves to an $ctrl(?) object. This objects should contain a measurement and will be updated whenever it receive a new data.

```
getMeasurements.latest(filter)     //only a object to filter through all measurements
    .then(function (latestMeasurement) {
        $ctrl.latestMeasurement = latestMeasurement;
});
```

My problem is that I don't know how to work with this data or display it in my html file. How does $ctrl work?

Here the [documentation](http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/api/c8y.core.service:c8yMeasurements#methods_latest) of the API

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**$ctrl** is the view model object in your controller. This $ctrl is a name you choose (**vm** is another most common name), if you check your code you can see the definition as **`$ctrl = this;`**, so basically its the **`this`** keyword of the controller function.

So now if you are using `$ctrl.latestMeasurement = 'someValue'`, then its like you are adding a property `latestMeasurement` to controller function.

Now how to use it in HTML?

To access the latestMeasurement property in HTML your code must have `<h1>{{$ctrl.latestMeasurement}}</h1>` (H1 tag is just an example.)

Here **$ctrl** is different from what I explained above on controller part. Here $ctrl is the value used for **`controllerAs`** property of the controller. But `$ctrl` is the default value of the `controllerAs` property, so your code may not have the controllerAs property defined, so Angular will take default value `$ctrl` in HTML.

This is where most people gets confused. So let me explain,

Assume in your new controller you have declared your `this` keyword to variable `vm`, and you set your `controllerAs` property to `myCtrl`, i.e;

`controllerAs: 'myCtrl'` while defining controller properties.

`var vm = this;` in your controller function.

In this case in js you have to use `vm` for setting values, and in HTML you have to use `myCtrl`. For example,

in JS controller function `vm.test = 'Hello world';`

in HTML `<span ng-bind="myCtrl.test"></span>`

The result **Hello world** will be displayed in your page.

Why $ctrl and not $scope?

The view model object model concept is introduced in AngularJS 1.5, it is actually part of migrating to Angular 2 where $scope no longer exsist. So in 1.5 they introduced new approch but did not removed $scope completely.

Hope the answer helped.

For basic Javascript concepts you can see http://javascriptissexy.com/16-javascript-concepts-you-must-know-well/

For more detailed AngularJS $ctrl concept you can see https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Comment: "_But `$ctrl` is the default value of the `controllerAs` property, so your code may not have the `controllerAs` property defined, so Angular will take default value `$ctrl` in HTML._" <<< [Moneyball](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are toking about  [this](http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/api/c8y.core.service:c8yMeasurements).

In this case, the

`$ctrl.latestMeasurement`

can means:

**$ctrl**, the controller where you are running this code. You can change it by $scope for example, and get the same result.

**latestMeasurement**, the variable where you want to store the last value of the measurement.

To explain my point of view let see the code below

```
<div ng-app="MeasurementApp">
  <div ng-controller="MeasurementController">
    <h1>{{latestMeasurement2}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

There you can see a simple angularjs app that shows a variable called latestMeasurement2 in a div and its controller called MeasurementController.  Then, to display the value let check your code.

```
angular.module('MeasurementApp', [])
  // creating the controller 
  .controller('MeasurementController', function(c8yMeasurements, $scope) {
      // creating the variable and let it empty by now.
      $scope.latestMeasurement2 = "";
      // Your code 
      var filter = {
        device: 10300,
        fragment: 'c8y_Temperature',
        series: 'T'
      };
      var realtime = true;
      c8yMeasurements.latest(filter, realtime)
         .then(function (latestMeasurement) {
                // The latestMeasurement is where the measurement comes
                // Here we just assign it into our $scope.latestMeasurement2
               $scope.latestMeasurement2 = latestMeasurement;
      }); 
   });
```

As the documentation says

```
   // $scope.latestMeasurement2 will be updated as soon as a new measurement is received.
   $scope.latestMeasurement2 = latestMeasurement;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `$ctrl, the controller where you are running this code. You can change it by $scope for example, and get the same result.` Not exactly. In the latest (post 1.4 I believe) versions of AngularJS, the component controller defaults to `$ctrl`, and you must access the property in the template as such. `$scope` throws the property implicitly into the template scope, and can be accessed directly.

Comment: I'm working with AngularJS some weeks now. I tried to change the $ctrl to a $scope already. I get only an empty object. So i thought i had to use the $ctrl. But i don't know really how.